# How can I convert an integer to a hexadecimal string in C?

Tags: c

How can I convert an integer to a hexadecimal string in C?

Example: The integer `50` would be converted to the hexadecimal string `"32"` or `"0x32"`.

Answer (score 54):

This code

```
int a = 5;
printf("%x\n", a);
```

prints

```
5
```

---

This code

```
int a = 5; 
printf("0x%x\n", a);
```

prints

```
0x5
```

---

This code

```
int a = 89778116;
printf("%x\n", a);
```

prints

```
559e7c4
```

---

If you capitalize the x in the format it capitalizes the hex value:

```
int a = 89778116;
printf("%X\n", a);
```

prints

```
559E7C4
```

---

If you want to print pointers you use the p format specifier:

```
char* str = "foo";
printf("0x%p\n", str);
```

prints

```
0x01275744
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `#` modifier instead of writing your own `0x`, especially with `%p` whose behavior is implementation-defined and might already include the `0x` for you.

Comment: Might want to mention `snprintf`, too.

Comment: Also, the format of your answer is confusing with the alternating blocks.  It may be useful to have just one code block with the results as comments after the statement.

Comment: @R.. Note that with `#`, the `"0x"` is not pre-pended when the value is 0.  `printf("%#X\n", 0);` --> `0`.  IMO, `printf("0x%X\n", a);` is worthy, keeping the `x` as lower case and `A-F` as upper. `0x559E7C4`

Answer (score 26):

The following code takes an **integer** and makes a **string** out of it in hex format:

```
int  num = 32424;
char hex[5];

sprintf(hex, "%x", num);
puts(hex);
```

gives

```
7ea8
```

Answer (score 21):

Usually with `printf` (or one of its cousins) using the `%x` format specifier.

Comment: You may want to at least give the signature or a link to a man page for `strtol`.

Comment: strtol() is the opposite of what he asked for.  That goes the wrong direction.

Comment: You can use `%X` for an upper case output.

Answer (score 15):

Interesting that these answers utilize `printf` like it is a given.
`printf` converts the integer to a Hexadecimal string value.

```
//*************************************************************
// void prntnum(unsigned long n, int base, char sign, char *outbuf)
// unsigned long num = number to be printed
// int base        = number base for conversion;  decimal=10,hex=16
// char sign       = signed or unsigned output
// char *outbuf   = buffer to hold the output number
//*************************************************************

void prntnum(unsigned long n, int base, char sign, char *outbuf)
{

    int i = 12;
    int j = 0;

    do{
        outbuf[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[num % base];
        i--;
        n = num/base;
    }while( num > 0);

    if(sign != ' '){
        outbuf[0] = sign;
        ++j;
    }

    while( ++i < 13){
       outbuf[j++] = outbuf[i];
    }

    outbuf[j] = 0;

}
```

Comment: missing `num` variable

Comment: You don't check for a base > 16. It should at least be in the header.

Also, I think you can leave the sign to the caller

Comment: You have to replace variable `num` by `n` in order to make this script work.

Answer (score 3):

I made a librairy to make Hexadecimal / Decimal conversion without the use of `stdio.h`. Very simple to use :

```c
char* dechex (int dec);
```

This will use `calloc()` to to return a pointer to an hexadecimal string, this way the quantity of memory used is optimized, so don't forget to use `free()`

Here the link on github : https://github.com/kevmuret/libhex/

Answer (score 1):

To convert an integer to a *string* also involves `char` array or memory management.

To handle that part for such short arrays, code could use a *compound literal*, since C99,  to create array space, [on the fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_fly).  The *string* is valid until the end of the block.

```
#define UNS_HEX_STR_SIZE ((sizeof (unsigned)*CHAR_BIT + 3)/4 + 1)
//                         compound literal v--------------------------v
#define U2HS(x) unsigned_to_hex_string((x), (char[UNS_HEX_STR_SIZE]) {0}, UNS_HEX_STR_SIZE)

char *unsigned_to_hex_string(unsigned x, char *dest, size_t size) {
  snprintf(dest, size, "%X", x);
  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  // 3 array are formed v               v        v
  printf("%s %s %s\n", U2HS(UINT_MAX), U2HS(0), U2HS(0x12345678));
  char *hs = U2HS(rand());
  puts(hs);
  // `hs` is valid until the end of the block
}
```

Output

```
FFFFFFFF 0 12345678
5851F42D
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those, who need to start from `string` in decimal representation (not from `int`).

1. Convert your string representation of the number to an integer value (you can use `int atoi( const char * str );` function
2. Once you have your integer you can print it as HEX using, for example, `sprintf` function with `%x` as a format parameter and you integer as a value parameter

Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/qIoHNW

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) { 
    int n;
    char hex_val[50];
 
    n = atoi("100663296");
    sprintf(hex_val, "%x", n);
 
    printf("%s", hex_val);
    return 0;
}
```