# Integer conversion to Hexadecimal String in C without (sprintf/printf libraries)

Tags: c, printf

I have these input variables:

```
 uint16 temperature = 0x1f12;
 uint8 array[8] = {0,0,0,...0}
```

And I want to have

```
array8[0] = '1';
array8[1] = 'f';
array8[2] = '1';
array8[3] = '2';
array8[4] = '\0';
array8[5] = '\0';
array8[6] = '\0';
array8[7] = '\0';
```

However, for memory problems (I'm working with microcontrollers!) I need to avoid functions such as sprintf, printf, puts, etc.

How should I do?

Best regards,

Comment: just shift & mask the values. Add `'0'` if between 0 and 9, else add `'A'-10`.

Comment: else add `'a' - 10` which is `'W'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968534/1477064

Comment: Should `array[]` write leading `0` digits?  Example: should `temperature = 0x123` --> `"123"` or `"0123"` or it makes no difference?

Comment: "for memory problems (uC) I need to avoid functions such as sprintf" ? sprintf should not use a lot of memory.

Comment: @Stargateur 'sprintf' consumes 800bytes in a 8KB flash memory in my microcontroller

Comment: @chux temperature = 0x123 --> "123"

Comment: @xvan I don't want to convert an integer to its hexadecimal .

Comment: Your edit breaks the existing answers. Also, `array8 = '1f12'` does not make any sense. Please rollback your question.

Comment: array8[0] = '1'; array8[1] = 'f'; array8[2] = '1'; array8[3] = '2'; array8[4] = 0 ... array8[7] = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses only 8 additional bytes in stack(`int i, j`).

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    array[7 - i] = temperature % 16;
    temperature /= 16;

    if (temperature == 0)
        break;
}

if (i == 8)
    i--;

int j;
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    array[j] = array[7 - i + j];
for (j = i + 1; j < 8; j++)
    array[j] = 0;

for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    if (array[j] < 10)
        array[j] += '0';
    else
        array[j] += 'a' - 10;
```

This code first converts `temperature = 0x1f12` to `array[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, 1, 2}`.

Then shifts the elements of `array` so that it becomes `array[8] = { 1, 15, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`.

And then converts the numbers to corresponding characters: `array[8] = { '1', 'f', '1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0' }`.

Note also that this if condition

```
    if (i == 8)
        i--;
```

is never met, since break condition always suffices in the first `for` loop, even for temperature >= 0x10000000. It's just there in the hope that it might help someone understand this code.

Comment: With `temperature = 0x123`, this answers forms array `"12300000"`, certainly not OP's goal.

Comment: @chux I think that's what OP wants..

Comment: OP's rely to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549385/integer-conversion-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c/44569241?noredirect=1#comment76096549_44549385) was ["123"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549385/integer-conversion-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c/44569241?noredirect=1#comment76114556_44549385), although OP did accept your answer, hmmm.

Comment: Sorry for my C level... I wanted what @nglee posted. Thank you for help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion to determine 1 hex digit at a time.

```
// print digit at the end and return the next address
static char *itohexa_helper(char *dest, unsigned x) {
  if (x >= 16) {
    dest = itohexa_helper(dest, x/16);
  }
  *dest++ = "0123456789abcdef"[x & 15];
  return dest;
}

char *itohexa(char *dest, unsigned x) {
  *itohexa_helper(dest, x) = '\0';
  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  char array[8];
  uint16_t temperature = 0x1f11;
  puts(itohexa(array, temperature));
  puts(itohexa(array, 0));
  puts(itohexa(array, 0x1234567));
  puts(itohexa(array, UINT_MAX & 0xFFFFFFF));
}
```

Output

```
1f11
0
1234567
fffffff
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but It generates the number in the reversed order.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True.  I 1st wrote it reversed as that makes the most sense, but then mis-read OP's desired order.  Hmmm `uint16 temperature = 0x89ab;` would have been clearer.  Will reverse.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fixed.

Comment: Alternative: https://ideone.com/wcpl10

Comment: @Stargateur Interesting.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Would it be possible to "pad" the output with a leading zero if it's below 4 digits? IE: `0x0B61` would be printed as `0b61` instead of just `b61`?

Comment: @Boyfinn Sure, of course code needs a modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
int convert()
{
 uint16_t temperature = 0x1f11;
 uint8_t array[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

 int i = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    array[i] = (0xf000 & temperature) >> 12 ;
    temperature <<= 4;
    printf("array[%d] = %x\n", i ,array[i]);
 }
 return(0);
}
```