# MSP430 inconsistent conversion from int to hex string

Tags: c, serial-port, uart, i2c, msp430

I'm having trouble converting some sensor readings to a hex string on my MSP430G2231.
I'm using this library: https://github.com/jwr/msp430_usi_i2c To read temperature data from a couple TI TMP117-sensors. The reading performs just fine and I've even done traces of the i2c data through a ligic analyzer and it looks all fine. I'm printing my results throught UART with this code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function configures Timer_A for full-duplex UART operation
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TimerA_UART_init(void)
{
    TACCTL0 = OUT;                          // Set TXD Idle as Mark = '1'
    TACCTL1 = SCS + CM1 + CAP + CCIE;       // Sync, Neg Edge, Capture, Int
    TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2;                // SMCLK, start in continuous mode
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function halts Timer_A
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TimerA_UART_halt(void)
{
    TACTL &= ~(MC_2);                       // SMCLK, stop
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Outputs one byte using the Timer_A UART
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TimerA_UART_tx(unsigned char byte)
{
    while (TACCTL0 & CCIE);                 // Ensure last char got TX'd
    TACCR0 = TAR;                           // Current state of TA counter
    TACCR0 += UART_TBIT;                    // One bit time till first bit
    TACCTL0 = OUTMOD0 + CCIE;               // Set TXD on EQU0, Int
    txData = byte;                          // Load global variable
    txData |= 0x100;                        // Add mark stop bit to TXData
    txData <<= 1;                           // Add space start bit
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Prints a string over using the Timer_A UART
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TimerA_UART_print(char *string)
{
    while (*string) {
        TimerA_UART_tx(*string++);
    }
}

#pragma vector = WDT_VECTOR
__interrupt void watchdog_timer (void)
{
  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits);     // Clear LPM3 bits from 0(SR)
}

#pragma vector = TIMERA0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0_ISR(void)
{
    static unsigned char txBitCnt = 10;

    TACCR0 += UART_TBIT;                    // Add Offset to CCRx
    if (txBitCnt == 0) {                    // All bits TXed?
        TACCTL0 &= ~CCIE;                   // All bits TXed, disable interrupt
        txBitCnt = 10;                      // Re-load bit counter
    }
    else {
        if (txData & 0x01) {
          TACCTL0 &= ~OUTMOD2;              // TX Mark '1'
        }
        else {
          TACCTL0 |= OUTMOD2;               // TX Space '0'
        }
        txData >>= 1;
        txBitCnt--;
    }
}
```

And the code for turning my uint16_t temperature readings to a hex string is done with this code:

```
static char *itohexa_helper(char *dest, unsigned x) {
  if (x >= 16) {
    dest = itohexa_helper(dest, x/16);
  }
  *dest++ = "0123456789abcdef"[x & 15];
  return dest;
}

char *itohexa(char *dest, unsigned x) {
  *itohexa_helper(dest, x) = '\0';
  return dest;
}
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549691/10035529 for this function.

And my code that iterates actually does the reading and prints out the temperature through uart looks like this:

```
for(i=0;i<SENSORS;i++)
{
    uint8_t b[2];
    pld[0] = tmp[i];
    pld[3] = tmp[i] + 1;
    i2c_send_sequence(pld, 6, b, LPM3_bits);
    while(!i2c_done());
    uint16_t n = (b[0] << 8) | b[1];
    TimerA_UART_print(itohexa(status,n));
}
```

Here `status` is defined as `char status[4]`.
The `UART_init();` and `UART_halt();` functions are called elsewhere outside the loop above.
What I'm getting on my UART-line for each sensor is exactly what I'd expect:
[image]
With the last two full bytes in the trace being the temperature (`0x0B` and `0x4C`), and printing these as-is yields the correct message, and my serial monitor recognizes these as both `0x0B` and `0x4C` as hex (not ASCII).

However, when converting these to a hex-string with the code above, my serial monitor only receives this for the same reading (`0x0B` and `0x4C`):
**b4ì** as ASCII and `0x62, 0x36, 0xEC` as raw hex.
The output I'm expecting from serial would be "0B4C" as ASCII.
And for the whole loop above, which reads through a total of 4 sensors, I'm expecting an output of "0B4C0B600B5C0B55" as ASCII, corresponding to these `uint16_t` readings: `0x0B4C,0x0B60,0x0B5C,0x0B55`.

However, I'm getting this:
**b4ìb6˜b5ìb55** in ASCII

and:
**0x62, 0x34, 0xEC, 0x62, 0x36, 0x98, 0x62, 0x35, 0xEC, 0x62, 0x35, 0x35** in raw hex

Comment: Please note that using recursion in embedded systems is a big "no-no". (Well, in most systems really...) You are risking stack overflow. Also your compiler might not be smart enough to switch the division by 16 for a 0xF masking. Apparently MSP430 has horrible performance when using division, so better stay clear of it if possible.

Comment: `uint16_t n = (b[0] << 8) | b[1];` This seems to deal with 16bit values. Your array `b` (when passed as `dest` parameter) can only hold 2 digits which only fits the hex digits of 8 bit values.

Comment: Whats `pld` defined as? In case it is an array of `uint8_t` or character type, then you have a bug here: `b[0] << 8`. Because of integer promotion, `b[0]` will get promoted to `int` and you invoke undefined behavior by shifting data into the sign bit. Correct code: `(uint16_t)b[0] << 8`.

Comment: @Gerhardh The "itohexa" function accepts only 16-bit unsigned integers, and the "i2c_send_sequence" outputs an "uint8_t*" pointer for two values.

Comment: Not really.`TimerA_UART_print` expects a nul-terminated string which is not what `itohexa` will provide. The array is not large enough for 2 digits + terminator. Finally, 16bit values can take 4 hex digits, not 2. You need 5 characters to store the hex digits of a 16bit value.

Comment: @Lundin pld is the i2c payload for requesting the temperatures from the sensor, it is a uint8_t array in this case. The payload sequence is shown in the image of the i2c trace above., which in this case goes like this:{0x90, 0x00, I2C_RESTART, 0x91, I2C_READ, I2C_READ};

Comment: Then you have one bug in the `b[0] << 8`. Might be more.

Comment: General note: You should not mix all those integer types. You provide a `uint16_t` to `itohexa` which expects a `unsigned int`. Keep your types consistent.

Comment: Btw a microcontroller-friendly hex string conversion would look something like this: `static void sane_itoa (uint8_t dst[5], uint16_t n) { for(uint8_t i=0; i<5; i++) { dst[5-i-1] = "0123456789abcdef"[n & 0xF]; n>>=4; } }`. This will zero pad too, but not null terminate. Strings sent over UART are often not null terminated.

Comment: @Lundin For some reason your conversion example function causes an error in my linker for a redefinition of "__int128" for some reason.

Comment: @Gerhardh Why are you pointing out that 16-bit values take 4 hex digits? Isnt a single uint8_t 2 digits long and an array of 2 would make a total of 4? Is there an assumption that contradicts this elsewhere in the code that I haven't noticed? Could you point it out please.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm sorry it totally slipped my mind that I'm using a separate character string called "status[4]" as my character buffer for printing the result. I'm not sure why in the snippet i gave the call for itohexa it gave ´b´ as it's parameter.

Comment: You convert 4 bit hex digits (e.g. value '15') into 8 bit characters (e.g.`'F'`). 4 hex digits of 4 bits each take 4 characters of 8 bits each. Plus 0 termination.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry again for the confusion. I've updated the code in the question to what it actually is at the moment I posted it.

Comment: @Lundin What's wrong `b[0] << 8 | b[1]`? This conversion method works perfectly for me when compiling for desktop?

Comment: Implicit promotion makes it `int` which is signed 16 on your system. If `b[0]` has MSB set, then  you end up left shifting data into the sign bit of this temporary signed 16 `int`, which is undefined behavior. As a result you can get incorrect code generation. For example a MSP430 C compiler is free to consider `0x80 << 8 | 0x8000` as always true, or to consider it as always false, or to halt and catch fire - it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin What would be the correct way to cast an `uint8_t*` to `uint16_t` on this system then?

Comment: @Lundin Would it be sufficient to just typecast like this: `(uint16_t)b[0]`?

Comment: Read my previous comments.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, I didn't notice your comment earlier. Sorry for that. I've now implemented the type casting in the way you described. Thank you for your input and patience with me :)