# How to check whether a hexadecimal number(%x) starts with a certain number or not in C?

Tags: c, hex

I'm working on an operating system related project now and there is one step which requires to check whether a hexadecimal number starts with `3` or not, using C.

Currently my idea is to convert that hexadecimal number into a string and check the initial character but just cannot find out any documentation for doing that. Anybody has any idea? Maybe just a hint.

Comment: What do you mean by a hexadecimal number?  Are you just wanting to know if the most significant byte of an integer is 0x03?

Comment: Generally (to me anyway) if you have a "hexadecimal number" then you already have a string.  Otherwise, you just call it an int. Or perhaps more specifically an unsigned int, or a uint32_t.

Comment: Converting to string is a terrible idea. Hex digits can be checked easily by bit masking. If your number is 8 bits, for example (2 hex digits), then checking if the first on is 3 is just `if (0x30 == (x & 0xF0))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of methods to convert a number to a hex string (`sprintf` comes to mind; [How can I convert an integer to a hexadecimal string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464194/2564301) list a few more) – but, why should you?

A full hex number is formed by converting each nibble (4 bits) to a hexadecimal 'digit'. To get just the first, you can divide your value by 16 until you have reached the final (= 'first', in the left-to-right notation common for both decimal and hexadecimal values) digit. If that's a 3 you are done.

Assuming `value` is an *unsigned* number:

```
while (value > 15)
     value >>= 4;
```

and then check if `value == 3`.

Comment: That's an elegant solution, now I'm kicking myself "why didn't I came up with this?" :)

Comment: Exactly that one looks more "computer science", honestly I'm thinking why I did not come up with it hahaa

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is not bad, you can use [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), it functions like `printf`/`fprintf` but instead of printing
on screen (or to be more precise: writing into a `FILE*` buffer), it stores the contents in a `char` buffer.

```
char value[16]; // more than enough space for 4 byte values

int reg = 0x3eef;

sprintf(value, "%x", reg);

if(value[0] == '3')
    printf("The hexadecimal number 0x%s starts with a 3.\n", value);
```

Comment: New knowledge got! Thank you for solving my problem

Comment: After converting your number to a string (why? that's not needed) why don't use it directly to save a little cpu with `printf("The....  0x%s ...\n2, value);` so you don't convert the number again to a string.

Comment: @LuisColorado because my intention was to show how to use `sprintf` and I did not focus of minimizing cpu cycles.

Comment: yes..... but you have done it once... why to do _the exact same conversion_ twice?

Comment: @LuisColorado like I said, my focus was on how to use `sprintf`, not on performance. I changed the `printf` to use `value` instead if `reg`, are you happy now?