# Decrement a hex value stored in a string

Tags: c

Let's assume I have:

```
char str[]="0x7fffffffe181"
```

basically I want to decrement the hex to `0x7fffffffe180`.

How do I do this?

<sub>Note: if the final character is letter e.g `c` after decrement it should be `b`</sub>

Comment: Will the strings represent numbers that can fit in a C `long` or `unsigned long`, or can they be arbitrarily long like `0xf876c6784564645de653654ee65d56310913bbba0009897768b`?

Comment: I'ts a schoolbook arithmatic problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Good luck with your assignment. :-)

Comment: Do you mean just `str[strlen(str) - 1]--`?

Comment: @RayToal it could be up to an `x64` architecture memory address or `0xffffffffffffffff`

Comment: Convert to a long long int, decrement, convert back to string. How to do the conversions is easily found on the interwebs.

Comment: Then covert to a long, decrement, and convert back. [Solutions are here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10156409/831878).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464194/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-c

Comment: You haven't really asked a question. What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only has to work in the range of an unsigned long long.

```
const char *eptr;
unsigned long long numeric = strtoull(str, &eptr, 16);
if (eptr == str || numeric == 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
sprintf(str, "0x%llx", numeric - 1);
```

We can't do this for signed hex in place because decrementing 0 or certain negative numbers would make the string longer.

In theory, 0 should work for the third argument to strtoull, but it's buggy in our libc right now so it doesn't.

Comment: `strtoull` takes 3 arguments. `base` is undeclared.

Comment: @melpomene: Fixed. I looked up strtoull and verified that 0 did what I wanted and still forgot to type it. :(

Comment: @Joshua your usage of `strtoull` is very wrong. You should read up on it before trying to use it.

Comment: I still don't understand that `eptr == base` check.

Comment: @melpomene: if strtoull is passed a pointer to something not a number, eptr will be the same as the pointer. If its passed a pointer to something that starts with a number, eptr points to after the end of the number. If it's just a number in the string, eptr is pointing at the null terminator.

Comment: `base` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @melpomene: My mistake. I started with base being the input variable and didn't fix it everywhere.

Comment: @JL2210: Not according to `man 3 strtoul`.

Comment: Yep. Just saw that. I guess that needs to be fixed in my implementation.

Comment: @Joshua, You answer turns `0x7fffffffe171` into `0xffffffffffffe170`

Comment: @amiTheregroot: Looks like we share the same buggy implementation. Use 16 until it can be fixed. Reporting bug now.

Comment: @JL2210: You probably don't care, but that wasn't bragging. I was expecting the question to require something too big for an integer type, which is a much harder problem.

Comment: @Joshua OK. I agree, that would be hard :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to an integer and back like this:

```
char *str2;
unsigned long long int len, a = strtoull(str, NULL, 16);
a--;
len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "0x%llx", a);
str2 = malloc(len+1);
sprintf(str2, "0x%llx", a);
```

Comment: What happens if `str` is `"0x0"`? I suppose the result will not fit into `str2` with size 3...

Comment: @StephanLechner Please see update.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the edit. Didn't catch that.

Comment: It's not portable, but `asprintf` would simplify this a bit.

Comment: I agree, but the operating system wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: @JL2210 your answer doesn't even decrement

Comment: @amiTheregroot What does `a--` do then?