# How to print numbers in HEX with printf in C?

Tags: c, printf, hal

How to print numbers in HEX with printf in C?

```
static void ReadReg_SI5338(uint8_t *pBuffer)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, SI5338_ADDR, pBuffer, 1, 5);
      if ( ret != HAL_OK )
      {
        printf("Error Tx\r\n");
      }
      else
      {
          ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c2, SI5338_ADDR, pBuffer, 1, 5);
          if ( ret != HAL_OK )
          {
              printf("Error Rx\r\n");
          }
          else
          {
              printf(pBuffer[0], "\r\n");
          }
      }
}
```

The code works, it reads correct values, but prints garbage in terminal. I'd like to have it in format "0x38", "0x01", etc. But i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can use [`printf("0x%x\r\n", pBuffer[0])`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464376/17200348)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print numbers in hex in C, use:

```c
printf("%#04x", number);
```

`#`: means include a `0x` before the number

`04`: mean padd the number with 2 zeros (aka if the number is `1`, it will print `0x01` instead of `0x1`, 4 cuz 2 for `0x`)

`x`: hex specifier

Comment: You probably meant `%#.2x`?

Comment: No, its `%#02x`, `0` means to use zeros to pad instead of spaces

Comment: `printf("%#02x", 0x1);` prints `0x1`. `printf("%#.2x", 0x1);` prints `0x01`.

Comment: opps should've been `%#04x`. I blame linux 0.0.1's printf for this (I usually use it's printf XD)

Comment: Please read about the difference between the width and the precision specifier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Width_field or https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: TBH learning all these hoops and quirks of printf format is pretty useless knowledge... That being said, the `04` means minimum field width (spaces, zeros, any character) of 4 and the `.2` means maximum digits 2. Zeroes instead of spaces is decided by the `%x` itself. The boring standard text is "For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, leading zeros (following any indication
of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding,"

Answer (score -1):

`printf("%#02x\r\n", pBuffer[0])`
For some reason it don't prints anything without \r\n.